# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, addeventlistener

I am using gulp for the first time and I don't know if this has nothing to do with this but in the console it says that it can't read addEventListener.

PS : Works fine with parcel..

I check if my variables was null but nothing happens

```
window.onload=function(){} doesn't work
```

HTML

```
<ul>
      <li class="kitchen">Cuisine</li>
      <li class="bathroom">Salle de bain</li>
  </ul>

  <form>
      <label>
          Cuisine
          <input name="kitchen" type="checkbox">
      </label>
      <label>
          Salle de bain
          <input name="bathroom" type="checkbox">
      </label>
  </form>
```

JS

```
let kitchenLight = document.querySelector('input[name=kitchen]');
let kitchen = document.querySelector('.kitchen');

kitchenLight.addEventListener('change', function(){
    kitchen.classList.toggle('on');
})
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Thanks for the help ! I have an exam in a couple of hours I really need to figure this out...

Comment: I have to use gulp it doesn't change anything  with what I usually do with parcel it's just the addEventListener issue that I don't know how to solve @Randy Casburn

Comment: 252 results:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+Uncaught+TypeError%3A+Cannot+read+property+%27addEventListener%27+of+null